# How to modify UDP packets in checksum field?

Tags: wireshark, packet

Stephen Northcutt, SANS Director, make a pcap contest (see [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-pcap-contest-actually-tells-us-stephen-northcutt)) where the `.pcap` file had a hidden information in checksum field. I solved it using wireshark and it was an interesting activity.
So, I would like to do some challenge based in the Stephen's contest. How can I modify a set of packets to do some contest like these?

In advance, I apologize if I'm using the wrong community to ask this question. I didn't found another more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different options. The easiest would be using a tool like [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy).

> Scapy is a powerful interactive packet manipulation program. It is
>   able to forge or decode packets of a wide number of protocols, send
>   them on the wire, capture them, match requests and replies, and much
>   more. It can easily handle most classical tasks like scanning,
>   tracerouting, probing, unit tests, attacks or network discovery (it
>   can replace hping, 85% of nmap, arpspoof, arp-sk, arping, tcpdump,
>   tethereal, p0f, etc.). It also performs very well at a lot of other
>   specific tasks that most other tools can't handle, like sending
>   invalid frames, injecting your own 802.11 frames, combining technics
>   (VLAN hopping+ARP cache poisoning, VOIP decoding on WEP encrypted
>   channel, ...), etc.

Comment: Now I don't remember if the information was in checksum field or was just found because of bad checksums. I will check it later. But your answer gave me the necessary elements to modify packets. Thank you.